# Form with a Grid that show my messages about the script while running

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have a script very long to scrape some page to internet. Now, with Pycharm I have a lot of "Print" command to see the error or what I download in the "Run window" of Pycharm, but I would to do it in a form page. So, I have created a form with a button to execute the script. At each for cycle I capture a lot of imformation tha I would to see in my form in Real Time (to see eventual errors). I think that I did everything, but when I execute the script I don't see the part of the form that show my messages...

This is the code

`import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import tkinter as tk
from getpass import getpass

from mysql.connector import connect, Error

def script():
    try:
        with connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="pct",
        ) as connection:
            print(connection)
###############AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT TO SEE. i USE THE text_response VARIABLE
                text_response = connection
##################
            select_movies_query = "SELECT coduffministero FROM reptribunale"
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(select_movies_query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
            for idufficio in result:
                ufficiotribunale = str(idufficio)
                for annoproc in range(2010, 2022):
                    annoprocedura = str(annoproc)
                    for rge in range (1, 100):

                #IN THI PART THERE IS THE CODE TO SCRUB
                #
                
##############IN THIS PART I PRINT THE text_response VARIABLE
               textwidget = tk.Text()
               textwidget.insert(tk.END, text_response)
               textwidget.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="WE")
##############
        except Error as e:
            print(e)

########## IN THIS FORM I WOULD TO SHOW MY MESSAGE IN REAL TIME    
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry ("900x550")
    window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    label = tk.Label(window, text="Premi il pulsante per cominciare a scaricare", font=("Helvetica", 15))
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N", padx=20, pady=10)
##########BUTTON TO EXECUTE THE SCRIPT    
    download_button = tk.Button(text="Scarica", command=script, font=("Helvetica", 15))
    download_button.grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky="WE", padx=10, pady=10)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        window.mainloop()`

and so,

Comment: you use a `tk.StringVar` inside your label ...then update that is "usually" how people do this ...

Comment: why dont you use logging?

Comment: How can i use logging or tk.stringvar?

Comment: You look it up in the documentation.  tk.StringVar is very common.